# Monero Daemon - cannot send transaction(s) no available connections

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, daemon, connection

Using Ledger Nano S
I have a 100% downloaded Blockchain - Synced ok ...
But the Daemon warns: "cannot send transaction(s) no available connections"

I assume that is the reason why - no matter if simple mode, advanced mode in gui or cli ... nothing works (gui - remaining wallet - blocks not loading // cli also not working) I can see my balance - but it is not available ... no sending possible at all.
How can I fix this ?

Is there any other Software to manage my Monero "on" Nano S. The Monero Gui (and cli) Wallet doesn't work here ar all and so I am stuck with coins, which I can see, but not access .... This is no goal for Monero :-(

Comment: Did you ever figure out what you needed to check to find out why you had no peers?

Answer (score 0):

This means exactly what it says: you have no peers (or no suitable peers) to which to send transactions. This happens at startup if you have transactions in your txpool, since you've not connected to the network just yet.

If it happens later, it can mean you've been disconnected from the network for a few minutes, or your daemon is forked from the network.

If you're using Tor and/or I2P, it can mean monerod cannot find enough peers of that type to keep an active connection all the time.

If you run "status" in the daemon, you'll get the current number of in and out connections to other monero peers. If you have 0 and 0, you are disconnected from the network.